# How can you get past a duplicate question filter error

Tags: support

I posted a question here but then I wanted to remain anonymous for a privacy reason just in case if other people from my company looks at the question and recognizes my account name.

I went ahead and deleted the question, then tried to repost the same question under a different account but now it's giving me the duplicate question error.

What can I do to get past this?

Comment: Can you explain this error a bit more?

Comment: @Jim it sounds like he posted a question, deleted it, then posted the same question verbatim under a different account but it gets flagged as duplicate

Comment: @enderland You've nailed it.

Comment: related (not a duplicate): [Is it a better idea to post at the Workplace with a different account?](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/517/168)

Answer (score 2):

The filter is pretty...bad, if Stack Overflow is any indication. I bet any minor change should allow you to post it on the different account. Try changing something minor so it isn't a letter for letter duplicate and post it again?